# Find the length of the curve $y = 1/2 (x^2 / 2 - \ln x), \, 1 ≤ x ≤ e$

Tags: calculus

How I can to find the length of the curve given by the graph of the function:

$$y = \frac 12 \left(\frac{x^2}{2} - \ln x\right), \quad 1 ≤ x ≤ e\qquad ?$$

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: $$L=\int_{1}^{e}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2}\,dx =\frac{1}{4}(e^2+1).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : the length of a curve $y=f(x)$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$ is given by $$\rm L = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 }  \rm dx $$